# Jquery drop down menu overlapping another

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have a table that displays product information.
[image: Product Listing]

Now when the user hovers over the "More" option against each row, it should show additional options - 5 of them to be precise.

I have a function that builds the "More" option dynamically

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".nav li").each(function () {

   more_html= "<ul><li><a href='#'>Option 1</a></li><li><a href='#'>Option 2</a></li><li><a href='#'>Option 3</a></li><li><a href='#'>Option 3</a></li><li><a href='#'>Option 4 </a></li><li><a href='#'>Option 5</a></li></ul> "

  $(this).append(more_html)
  });
});
```

and another event that attaches the drop down functionality to the the "More". I am using JQuery drop down plug in.

```
jQuery('.nav li').live('hover', function() {

  $('.nav li').hover(function () {
     clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
     $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(200);
  }, 

  function () {
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
      $('ul', this).stop(true, true).slideUp(200);
    }, this), 200));

  });
});
```

Now over to the problem.

When I hover over the More link on the first row, the menu drops down. 
But when i move mouse down through the menu, I hit on the "More" link on the second row, and that cause I losing the more drop down for the first row. Now it shows the More option drop down for the second row.

I believe I need a way to disable the hover option on the More menu on second or later rows when a menu is already in place. 
But i am unable to do so!

Does giving a higher z-index for the drop down help?  I been struggling with this for a while now. please help!

Comment: When you hover over the first "more" link, does it slip behind the next link or overlay it?

Comment: it does over lay. the problem is when i moved down the menu and when i reach the next more, the menu for the first one disappear and the second one pops down. I need the first one to stay regardless the mouse is hovering over the second "more"

Answer (score 0):

Quick guess would be your CSS. Your second function sets a hover for .nav li, which is appended with another inner li, which in turn supposedly also anwers to the .nav li script. could you maybe post the relevant CSS for some more info?

Comment: I made a quick mockup for you with your code: http://jsbin.com/ujewuw/3/edit#javascript,html,live